# Python: How to preserve leading zeroes when reading in pandas a #0000000000 formatted excel column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel file with a column with custom formatting #0000000000. If I read it into a pandas data frame with either of these three commands

```
pd.read_excel("Formatted_File.xlsx", dtype=str)
```

or

```
pd.read_excel("Formatted_File.xlsx", dtype="object")
```

or just

```
pd.read_excel("Formatted_File.xlsx")
```

I get a data with cut off zeros.

Without going into details, but let's assume I cannot change the Custom Formatting of the input Excel file. How can I preserve the leading zeros while reading the file to pandas data frame?

Comment: Have you tried being more specific with the dtype parameter? I.e. providing it a dictionary `{'specific_column_name': 'object'}`?

Comment: @DataJanitor yes, I did and it also didn't work

Comment: Because it's just an Excel format style but the real recorded value is a number.

Comment: Excel stores anything that looks like a number as a number. There are no leading 0s in a number. You actually have to *force* Excel to store eg VAT or Social Security numbers as text by adding a `'` at the front. Excel will mark such cells with a colored triangle at the top left of the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read the displayed values as it with `Pandas` (probably it's possible with `openpyxl`) because the value is stored as a number (1, 2, 3, ...) but the column has a custom format (#0000000000).

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', dtype={'UID': str})
print(df)

# Output
   UID
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    8
8    9
9   10
```

You can recreate the column format with `str.zfill`:

```
df['UID'] = df['UID'].str.zfill(10)
print(df)

# Output
          UID
0  0000000001
1  0000000002
2  0000000003
3  0000000004
4  0000000005
5  0000000006
6  0000000007
7  0000000008
8  0000000009
9  0000000010
```